# synthesis of lead hydroxide

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

what is the best and cheapest way to do it? I tried solving lead in HCl but only a little of lead reacts with HCl so I used electrolysis to speed up the reaction but still a little lead reacted. is it because of soloubility of PbCl2? if I use nitric acid will it work better( soloubility of lead nitrate is more than others)?

Comment: Yes, poor solubility of PbCl2 is quite probably the issue.

Comment: The insoluble salt increases the oxidation potential but can cause mechanical problems if the salt is adherent; the reaction takes longer. For a small amount electrolysis in HCl and patience should work, otherwise nitric acid. Just curious why make lead hydroxide?

Comment: can I directly make Pb(OH)2 by electrolysing water? for example use CuSO4 as electrolit?

Comment: by adding H2O2 to Pb(OH)2, red lead is made. I want for making red lead.